# How to implement ActionListeners to my game?

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener, mouse-listeners

I am a 15 year old new to the stackoverflow community. I am currently trying to independently develop a Rock Paper Scissors game using java. I thought working on this project would be an informing experience to help me learn java and its fundamentals. I am somewhat new with the java programming language so please do not criticize me, I am slowly learning by trial and error. For this particular project, I decided to use Eclipse as I like its user interface better than other IDEs. Anyway, I decided to implement JPanel to make the game more visual. My code is as follows copy and pasted from my eclipse project:

```
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public abstract class prompt extends JPanel implements ActionListener {     
    public static void main(String []args) {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        JButton rockButton = new JButton("ROCK");
        JButton scissorsButton = new JButton("SCISSORS");
        JButton paperButton = new JButton("PAPER");
        JFrame choicePrompt = new JFrame("Rock, Paper, Scissors Game");

        choicePrompt.add(panel);
        choicePrompt.setSize(300, 300);
        choicePrompt.setVisible(true);

        panel.add(rockButton);
        panel.add(scissorsButton);
        panel.add(paperButton);
    }
}
```

PLEASE READ: I made the prompt class an abstract class because apparently it fixed an error. However, what I'm looking for is a way to add that when the rock, paper, or scissors button is clicked on the JPanel, that it registers that click. I know this can be acheived with either a Mouse or ActionListener but I could not figure it out on my own. All the other "shtuff" like the computerchoice I can potentially do on my own.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html

Comment: Start by having a read through [Creating a GUI With JFC/Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/), [How to Use Buttons, Check Boxes, and Radio Buttons](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html) and [How to Write an Action Listener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html)

Comment: Ordinary, I would vote to close this type of question, as it can easily be answered by spending some reading the tutorials or searching SO for similar questions, but I'll cut you some slack for trying to teach yourself and your inexperience and because arbitrarily closing a question to a new comer can be seen as rather anti-social.  In future, you might want highlight the efforts you have made to solve the problem on your own ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> PLEASE READ: I made the prompt class an abstract class because apparently it fixed an error

It might have fixed the compiler error, but it won't have fixed the problem.

You class implements an `interface` in this case the `ActionListener` interface.  Basically, an `interface` is a contractual agreement that means that classes the implement the `interface` will fulfil the requirements of the interface, in this case, this means providing an implementation of the `actionPerformed` method declared by the `ActionListener` interface

Start by having a read through [What Is an Interface?](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/interface.html), [Creating a GUI With JFC/Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/), [How to Use Buttons, Check Boxes, and Radio Buttons](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html) and [How to Write an Action Listener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html)

Comment: Thanks, at least I fixed that; however, I am still not getting any luck with using the "How to Write an Action Listener" java tutorial you sent me. Elaboration might be needed.

Answer (score -1):

Why exactly is your class abstract? I assume you are forgetting to implement something, and making it abstract doesn't necessarily fix that.

Answer (score -1):

to add a ActionListener to a JButton ...this is what i usually do...:

```
public class ButtonHandler implements ActionListener
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
    {

    if(event.getActionCommand().equals("0"))//.getActionCommand() returns the text in the component
        {
            //do what you want here...
        }
            }
}
```

now to make it function just

```
btn0.addActionListener(new ButtonHandler());//ButtonHandler is the name of the class that implements the ActionListener, btn0 is the name of the JButton
```